# 2nd configuration for Bash complete to work independently of TAB completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Is it possible to have a second configuration for Bash's `complete` which operates independently of the standard `TAB` triggered one?

I've written a Bash filename completion script tailored specifically for my purposes but I do not want to replace `TAB` completion with it. Instead I'd like to map it to different keys (e.g. `Ctrl+F` or an `F#` key) so that I can use it easily when needed but continue to use `TAB` completion most of the time.

At the moment I have a line in my `.bashrc` for testing my script which works fine:

```
complete -o nospace -o filenames -C /path/to/complete_script commands_list
```

How do I configure custom keys to trigger my completion script without interfering with `TAB` completion?

Answer (score 2):

If your custom completion is designed only for `commands_list`, this should work: bind `complete` command to a second key combination, and check value of `$COMP_KEY` in your script (this is a decimal character code of last character in the key sequence).  If it's `9` (regular tab), do the default filename completion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If it is a `tab` how do I perform the default filename completion? i.e. Pass the completion back to Bash to handle.